# Twitter embedded timeline never updates

Tags: javascript, twitter, embedding

We're using the Twitter Embedded Timeline widget which is documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines#user).

According to the documentation, it is supposed to auto-update its self "in real time":

> These new timeline tools are built specifically for the web, mobile
>   web, and touch devices. They load fast, scale with your traffic, and
>   update in real-time.

But it is not doing that. The iframe loads fine initially, but then never updates. When I watch the network tab in the Chrome developer tools, I don't see any errors, or further network requests for data.

Has anyone else noticed this? Is the documentations simply incorrect and that functionality doesn't exist? I'm using the this code snippet, provided by Twitter:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-screen-name="foxnews" data-widget-id="11111111111111" data-chrome="nofooter noheader noscrollbar transparent" data-tweet-limit="10"></a> 
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?"http":"https";if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
  if (typeof(twttr) !== "undefined") {
    twttr.widgets.load();
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
The updates *will* appear if I use the snippet exactly as-is from the wizard/generator. However when I add the customization data attributes, it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is the expected behavior when using `data-tweet-limit="#"` to customize the number tweets which appear. When I remove this attribute the widget polls for updates again.

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to be out of date. Can you try this and see if it works?

`<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/FoxNews" data-widget-id="591265000628559874">Tweets by @FoxNews</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>`

If it does, you can create your own widget (make sure you're logged in to Twitter first) [here.](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new)

Comment: I created a new widget from the widgets "dashboard" and dropped it into a static page and it's not updating. The only thing I added was `data-screen-name="foxnews"` because they tweet frequently.

Comment: @SDP What precisely are you trying to customise? Can you not add the customisation you need from the new widget wizard on Twitter?

Comment: No the wizard just links to the docs page on how to add data-attributes for customization. Im using noheader, nofooter, user-name, transparent

Comment: @SDP What wizard are you using? Have you not tried using the link I put above?

Comment: @SDP you tried using the example code I posted above?

Comment: @SDP Can you not just use that then?

Comment: No. Definitely not. For one thing, the Twitter user name is dynamic... So we MUST use that attribute. The header and footer are also inappropriate for our application. That's the point if this question